# Can I plug a 8-pin EPS connector from the PSU to a 4-pin ATX motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, atx, eps

The PSU for my motherboard just died and I was able to get a used one from a friend. Trouble is, this PSU I got from him doesn't have the 4-pin ATX power cord that powers the CPU. It only has an EPS 8-pin one. My question is, could I just use the EPS 8-pin and plug it to the motherboard, leaving the extra 4 pins hanging? Or do I have to get an adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I think so. The 8 pin connector is in fact two 4 pin connectors, if I remember correctly.

[Here](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/EPS12V_-_EATX12V_8_pin)'s a link with picture. The 8 pin connector is indeed composed of two 4 pin connectors.